# not quite sure how to do random block generation for a rhythm-style game

Tags: java, random, block

I am developing a game, and the principle of the game is a bit like a rhythm game- you need to press a button/click the screen right on the incoming red blocks which are all lined up in a black line(sorry I can't post pics due to low reputation) . The thing is, I want the game to be like a mini game where the red blocks will spawn randomly, sometimes as a 'long note' and sometimes as 'short note', but I can't think of a way to do this efficiently. So far I have created two block variables with random number of gaps between each other, but I can't shake of the fear that this is quite unnecessary. Here's the code for the blocks-

```
package com.jollygent.game;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.Random;

public class Hitbox {


private int x,y;
BufferedImage hitbox;
Random random;
BufferedImage hitbox2;
private int gap;


public Hitbox(int x,int y,GamePanel game) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    SpriteSheet ss = new SpriteSheet(game.getSheet());

    hitbox = ss.getImage(1,2,64,64);
    hitbox2 = ss.getImage(1,2,64,64);
    random = new Random();
    gap = random.nextInt(128) + 64;
}

public void update() {
    if(x < -GamePanel.WIDTH) {
       x = GamePanel.WIDTH;
       gap = random.nextInt(128) + 64;
    }

    x-= 6;
}

public void render(Graphics g) {

    g.drawImage(hitbox,x,y,null);
    g.drawImage(hitbox2,x + gap,y,null);



}

}
```

how should I approach this?